# Custom comparator for multiset that contains pointers to objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Sorry for the unclear title, actually I couldn't think of a title that describes my problem concisely.

But the question is simple to state. I have a Node class. I want to maintain order among its objects by its id_ field. I know that making a multiset<Node> will correctly maintain the order in the container if I overload < operator in Node class or provide a Comparator object in multiset. But I want to declare a multiset<Node*> container and want to achieve the same behaviour.

Here is my Node class definition:

```
class Node {
        int id_;
        ...
        public:
        Node() {
                ...
        }
        int getId() {
                return id_;
        }
        void setId(int id) {
                id_ = id;
        }
        ...
        bool operator<(const Node &input) {
                return (this->id_ < input.id_);
        }
};
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you mean and what you need is this:

```
template <typename T, typename Pred = std::less<T>>
struct ptr_compare : Pred
{
    ptr_compare(Pred const & p = Pred()) : Pred(p) { }

    bool operator()(T const * p1, T const * p2) const
    {
        return Pred::operator()(*p1, *p2);
    }
};

typedef std::multiset<Node*, ptr_compare<Node>> node_ptr_set;
```

You can use the `ptr_compare` template for any container that requires a binary predicate and you want to apply the predicate indirectly.

Comment: Seems esoteric at first site. Isn't there some other simpler way? Or could you please take some pain and explain it? Thanks!

Comment: @Prab: It's just a wrapper that takes pointers and forwards them dereferenced to the original predicate... what point needs explaining? Do you know how `std::less<T>` works?

Comment: Yes, but what is Pred? Everything else I understood.

Comment: @Prab it is a template parameter, defaulting to `std::less<T>`. It allows you to use your own comparison logic in `ptr_compare`, which makes sense, since comparisons should not be limited to less-than.

Comment: It might be obvious, but the reason we use inheritance rather than composition is so that we can take advantage of empty base optimisations, since trait classes like this are usually empty.